# LearnYouNode Excercise "Juggling Async" optional solutions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

in the "LearnYouNode" excercise i have following question to the task 9. In the hints, there is mentioned, that this excercise could also be done with the packages "asycn" or "after". I tried it with both and both failed :|
(i have already done the recommended solution with no additional package)

Here are my miserable attempts:

Shared code of both variants:

```
var http = require("http");
var bl = require("bl");
var after = require("after");
var async = require("async");
var results = [];

//getting the 3 arguments
var urls = []
for(var i = 2; i < process.argv.length; i++){
    urls.push(process.argv[i]);
}
function printResults(){
  for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
      console.log(results[i]);
  }
}
```

"after" attempt:

```
//Understood it that way printResults is called after the var next is 3 times generated, no result at all
var next = after(3, printResults)
for(i = 0; i<urls.length;i++){
    next(i);
}

var next = function (i){
    http.get(urls[i], response => {
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        var singleString = "";
       response.on("data", data =>{
         singleString += data;
       }).on("end",function() {
          results.push(singleString);
       });

       response.on("error", err => {
          return console.log(err);
       });

    });
}
```

"asycn" attempt:

```
// I get output but in the wrong order
async.map(urls,function(url, printResults) {
    http.get(url, response => {

        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        var singleString = "";
       response.on("data", data =>{
         singleString += data;
       }).on("end",function() {
          console.log(singleString);
       });

       response.on("error", err => {
          console.log(err);
       });

    });
}, function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

I really don´t get what i am doing wrong. Thank you very much for your help. Kind regards,
SirSandmann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about syntax, you should read docs more carefully.

For `async`:

```
var http = require('http');
var urls = process.argv.slice(2);
var async = require('async');

// the second parameter is a callback provided by async
// it allows async to know when your async task is done
async.map(urls, (url, next) => {
    http.get(url, response => {
        var str = '';
        response
            .on('data', data => str += data)
            .on('end', () => next(null, str)); // we use the callback here to give the data back
    });
}, (err, results) => {
    // the second callback is not an error handler
    // it's called when all async jobs are done
    // so the logging of the results goes here
    results.forEach(res => console.log(res));
});
```

For the `after` solution, you declared `next()` twice and you don't use the original next() in your `http.get()`:

```
var http = require('http');
var urls = process.argv.slice(2);
var after = require('after');

var results = [];
function printResults() {
    results.forEach(res => console.log(res));
}

// when you call next(), it tells after 'hey, my async job is done'
var next = after(3, printResults);

urls.forEach((url, i) => {
    http.get(url, response => {
        var str = '';
        response
            .on('data', data => str += data)
            .on('end', () => {
                // after is very "dumb", you have to store your result yourself at the right index
                results[i] = str;
                // this is very important, 'hey, my async job is done'
                next();
            });
    });
});
```

In both solutions, you noticed there is a callback (I called it `next` in both), in asynchronous Javascript, a callback is the only way to notify an asynchronous job is done. That why it's important in both examples to call the provided callback.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for the explanation! I whish i could give this answer more than one upvote!

Comment: @SirSandmann No problem, one more thing, `after` seems obsolete, `async` is much more powerful and comprehensive for async control flow. Also, take your time to fully grasp the callback concept, it's used pretty much everywhere in JS and you can't do much without it. The next step would be learning about promises but do it once you're familiar enough with callbacks.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, the callback concept is new to me, i hope i will get familiar  with it fast :) I already heard about promises on the firefox developer site.